# Oracle Database problem "Invalid PathException"

Tags: java, oracle, ojdbc

I am trying to connect to oracle java with jdbc but the problem ist that I got the error of invalid path!!
it shows a gap in the url but I actually do not give a link to the java but a long oracleJdbcUrl, like this:

```
"jdbc:oracle:thin:@" +
  "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" +
  "(HOST=myoracle.db.server)(PORT=1521))" +
  "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=my_servicename)))";
```

but I get the following error in the console:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe" -ea -Didea.test.cyclic.buffer.size=1048576 "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar=56011:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.3\lib\idea_rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit5-rt.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.3\plugins\junit\lib\junit-rt.jar;D:\Gino Simulator\Gino_Simulator\target\classes;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ojdbc8\18.3.0.0\ojdbc8-18.3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\jdbc\ucp\18.3.0.0\ucp-18.3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\security\oraclepki\18.3.0.0\oraclepki-18.3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\security\osdt_cert\18.3.0.0\osdt_cert-18.3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\security\osdt_core\18.3.0.0\osdt_core-18.3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\ha\simplefan\18.3.0.0\simplefan-18.3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\com\oracle\database\ha\ons\18.3.0.0\ons-18.3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\junit\junit\4.13.2\junit-4.13.2.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\org\hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-sql-oracle_2.12\0.0.2\zio-sql-oracle_2.12-0.0.2.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\org\scala-lang\scala-library\2.12.15\scala-library-2.12.15.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-sql-jdbc_2.12\0.0.2\zio-sql-jdbc_2.12-0.0.2.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-sql_2.12\0.0.2\zio-sql_2.12-0.0.2.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio_2.12\2.0.0-RC5\zio_2.12-2.0.0-RC5.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-internal-macros_2.12\2.0.0-RC5\zio-internal-macros_2.12-2.0.0-RC5.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-stacktracer_2.12\2.0.0-RC5\zio-stacktracer_2.12-2.0.0-RC5.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\izumi-reflect_2.12\2.1.0\izumi-reflect_2.12-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\izumi-reflect-thirdparty-boopickle-shaded_2.12\2.1.0\izumi-reflect-thirdparty-boopickle-shaded_2.12-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-streams_2.12\2.0.0-RC5\zio-streams_2.12-2.0.0-RC5.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-schema_2.12\0.1.9\zio-schema_2.12-0.1.9.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-schema-macros_2.12\0.1.9\zio-schema-macros_2.12-0.1.9.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-prelude_2.12\1.0.0-RC7\zio-prelude_2.12-1.0.0-RC7.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-prelude-macros_2.12\1.0.0-RC7\zio-prelude-macros_2.12-1.0.0-RC7.jar;C:\Users\fakhari\.m2\repository\dev\zio\zio-schema-derivation_2.12\0.1.9\zio-schema-derivation_2.12-0.1.9.jar" com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter -ideVersion5 -junit4 Connectiontest,givenOracleSID_thenCreateConnectionObject

java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 45: D:\work\tools\oracle\product\18.0.0\client_1\ \network\admin\ojdbc.properties

    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:172)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:229)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147)
    at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PropertiesFileUtil.validatePath(PropertiesFileUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PropertiesFileUtil.loadDefaultFiles(PropertiesFileUtil.java:204)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PropertiesFileUtil.loadPropertiesFromFile(PropertiesFileUtil.java:137)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.getConnectionPropertiesFromFile(PhysicalConnection.java:9880)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.readConnectionProperties(PhysicalConnection.java:1042)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:739)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:38)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:704)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:228)
    at Connectiontest.givenOracleSID_thenCreateConnectionObject(Connectiontest.java:17)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

could anybody help please??

Comment: Can you post code where you actually use this oracleJdbcUrl to connect to database?

Comment: You need to check the content of your properties file D:\work\tools\oracle\product\18.0.0\client_1\ \network\admin\ojdbc.properties

Comment: @JeandeLavarene but it seems the problem is because of space in the url here: lient_1\ \network\ ... and I donno how to solve it

Comment: With no further information I would guess that this problem is caused by a dodgy environment variable value. What are the values of the environment variables `ORACLE_HOME` and `TNS_ADMIN`?

Comment: Check your T_WORK environment variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem with changing the Version of OJDBC to the older one!
now I am using ojdbc8 and it works!
it seems that was incompatible with something else!